# MySql Stored procedure shows as error in syntax

Tags: mysql

I am new to creating procedures in mysql, i know how to create them in MSSQL, but i am not sure what is wrong with this, it says `Syntax Error Near END`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetNameByID(IN CustID INT)
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = CustID
  END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query in your procedure needs a semi colon after it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetNameByID(IN CustID INT)
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = CustID;
  END
```

You may also need to set the delimiter to something. The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) does this:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE GetNameByID(IN CustID INT)
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = CustID;
  END//
```

(but obviously not with your query)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the ; at the end of select statement